# Deleting rows from numpy array not working

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix

I am trying to split my `numpy` array of data points into test and training sets. To do that, I'm randomly selecting rows from the array to use as the training set and the remaining are the test set.

This is my code:

```
matrix = numpy.loadtxt("matrix_vals.data", delimiter=',', dtype=float)
matrix_rows, matrix_cols = matrix.shape

# training set 
randvals = numpy.random.randint(matrix_rows, size=50)
train = matrix[randvals,:]
test = numpy.delete(matrix, randvals, 0)

print matrix.shape
print train.shape
print test.shape
```

But the output I get is:

```
matrix.shape: (130, 14)
train.shape: (50, 14)
test.shape: (89, 14)
```

This is obviously wrong since the number of rows from train and test should add up to the total number of rows in the matrix **but here it's clearly more**. Can anyone help me figure out what's going wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you are generating random integers *with replacement*, `randvals` will almost certainly contain repeat indices.

Indexing with repeated indices will return the same row multiple times, so `matrix[randvals, :]` is guaranteed to give you an output with exactly 50 rows, regardless of whether some of them are repeated.

In contrast, `np.delete(matrix, randvals, 0)` will only remove *unique* row indices, so it will reduce the number of rows only by the number of unique values in `randvals`.

Try comparing:

```
print(np.unique(randvals).shape[0] == matrix_rows - test.shape[0])
# True
```

To generate a vector of *unique* random indices between 0 and `1 -  matrix_rows`, you could use [`np.random.choice`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/reference/generated/numpy.random.choice.html) with `replace=False`:

```
uidx = np.random.choice(matrix_rows, size=50, replace=False)
```

Then `matrix[uidx].shape[0] + np.delete(matrix, uidx, 0).shape[0] == matrix_rows`.

Comment: Thanks! That was exactly the problem

Answer (score 3):

Why not use scikit learn's [train_test_split](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cross_validation.train_test_split.html) function instead and avoid all the hassle?

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split

train, test = train_test_split(mat, test_size = 50.0/130.0)
```

Comment: Is this going to give me a random split?

EDIT: Just checked the doc and it does! Thanks for the alternate solution! I didn't know about this function. I'd still like to know why my code doesn't work though

Comment: Yes.  You can test it for yourself if you would like.  Check the documentation on the link in my answer above for info on how it works and what parameters it takes.